# HTACCESS rule leading to 404 across site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a URL from:

```
http://domain.com/book.php?id=1
```

To:

```
http://domain.com/1
```

I set the following rule in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I don't know why this rule leads to everything on the domain returning a header of 404 (not found). Other rules in the file have no effect as I tried to remove them but still 404 appears.

Comment: Can you clarify which URLs are actually giving 404 to you?

Comment: any URL even the domain homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule with `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /book.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what these lines mean? Thanks :)

Comment: It just means to avoid rewrite if request if for a valid file or directory.

Comment: What does valid file mean? isn't book.php a valid file itself? Sorry, mod rewrite is one of the hardest things to grasp for me

Comment: Yes `/book.php` is a valid file and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means don't apply rewrite rule when file is valid to `/book.php` will not be impacted by this rewrite rule. Remember rewrite rules are applied again and again until all conditions fail to execute.